# 2005 Ford Escape (Hybrid) Hood Ajar alarm triggered when left blinker is on

Tags: electrical, ford, sensor, escape

I seem to be having an electrical issue with my 2005 Ford Escape Hybrid. Whenever using the left blinker, the Hood Ajar alarm goes off and continues beeping until the blinker is turned off. It does not happen with the right blinker. I've tried opening/closing the hood, and the sensor button seems to be firmly compressed when the lid is closed.